# Подскажите технологию для работы с таблицами в web + php?

Tags: php, таблицы

Подскажите технологию для работы с таблицами в web'е в связке с php.

Что нужно получить:

- Таблица с фиксированным количеством именованных столбцов
- Возможность добавлять строки
- Обработка через PHP (Из-за знаний на начальном уровне)

Может что-то существует уже готовое? гугл не дает ответа.

Comment: datatables - https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю обратить внимание на следующие ссылки:

[Генератор HTML таблицы №1](https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush)

[Генератор HTML таблицы №2](https://github.com/iranianpep/php-table-generator)

[Генератор HTML таблицы №3](https://github.com/laSyntez/TableGenerator)